# How to portably include Windows' runtime library to binary PHP CLI

Tags: php, dll, windows-runtime

I'm working on small app which users can download and which includes a php file and binary version of interpreator PHP for Windows (PHP CLI). All is packed in one .zip folder and as we know to start build-in PHP server it's enough to unzip the folder on any hard disk, add the path to binaries to the PATH variable and then in the command line go to the folder and execute

```
php -S localhost:80
```

But as we also know to make PHP working on Windows, we need also respective runtime library. For example for the latest PHP 7.3 we need VC CRT 14 (Visual Studio 2015). I would like to pack it also in my zip, but as "portable" i.e. without a need to run an installator and if possible even without copying to `C:/Windows/System32` I mean we just unpack only one zip folder on any disk, run the cmd-command and everything to be working without additional actions.

On the page http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.requirements.php I read that it's possible to gather all installed DLL files. How can I do that? Maybe there is ready-made list of the files? (I'm primarly interesting in VC 14 for PHP 7.3, but it may be also VC 11 for PHP 5.6)

Is it possible then to include the library to binary PHP CLI without installation the library and even without copying its files to the `System32` folder?

Have someone an experience in something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it turns out that it's enough only to download [vcruntime140.dll](https://www.dll4free.com/vcruntime140.dll.html) from Internet and put the file in the PHP 7.3 folder to make PHP CLI working on Windows. No need to install something or even copy to the `Windows/System32` folder.

Comment: Is there a specific version of vcruntime140.dll required? Trying to run this in a Windows nanoserver with no luck.